# What is the webkit version for chrome on Android v4.0.4

Tags: android, google-chrome, webkit

Guys I want to know what is the webkit version for Chrome on Android v4.0.2 and v4.0.4 Also the webkit version for Android browser for version 4.0.2 and v4.0.4?

What I have searched resulted in this For Android browser is v534.30 
For chrome is v534.46.0

Please correct me if I am wrong on this....

Answer (score 0):

There is not a particular version of WebKit that is used on Chrome per revision of Android.  The version of WebKit is tied to the version of the browser that the user has installed from the Play Store.

If you want to know the version of WebKit used in any version of Chrome you can use the tools here http://omahaproxy.appspot.com/ with more information here http://dev.chromium.org/developers/calendar

Comment: @RyanMcDonough if you are talking about the recent change to Blink then maybe, however Chrome on Android right this instant uses WEbKit and the answer I gave IS the way you find the version of Webkit being using in Chrome as Chrome updates from the store and not on AOSP